# Minor ticklines in Y axis is not showing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a log-log plot where minor ticklines shows only in x axis not in y axis. Because my y-axis major ticks are not spaced like x-axis.
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmGnl.png)

Here is my code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


z = np.loadtxt("msd_profile2.out",delimiter=' ',skiprows=200005)[:, 5]
y= np.loadtxt("msd_profile2.out",delimiter=' ',skiprows=200005)[:, 4]
x=np.loadtxt("msd_profile2.out",delimiter=' ',skiprows=200005)[:, 3]
time =np.loadtxt("msd_profile2.out",delimiter=' ',skiprows=200005)[:, 2]
xy= (np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))
plt.rc('font', size=18,family='serif')
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize='x-small')
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize='x-small')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(time, z,label="Z")
ax.plot(time, xy,label="XY")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('MSD')


ax.legend()

plt.savefig('H:/figure/msd_ar12.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

How can I add customize tick spacing in yaxis? I think it suppose to be done by default.

Answer (score 0):

read the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html) documentation. It appear minor ticks are turned off by default.

You may need to import from matplotlib.ticker to get the MultipleLocator to specify the frequency of your ticks.